# Check Database for Null Value - Classic ASP

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I have a SQL database with the following fields, field A field B field C etc

I need to be able to check if any recordsets have null values but for only the fields i want to have checked, E.G i only want to check field A and B.

I need the script to check all of the RS for the fields i have chosen and if any have a null value i just need this to give me an error or a message.

Something like and if statement

If RS fields not null Do something ELSE
Do something else
End if

Any ideas would be great.

Thanks

I now have the following code kind of working!

```vb
While ((Repeat2__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT Recordset2.EOF))

    If (Recordset2.Fields.Item("compost").Value) = "" OR         (Recordset2.Fields.Item("assessment_period").Value) = "" Then
        Response.Write("This field is Empty")
    Else
        Response.Write("This field is not Empty")
    End If

    Repeat2__index=Repeat2__index+1
    Repeat2__numRows=Repeat2__numRows-1
    Recordset2.MoveNext()
Wend
```

This then gives me the following output

This field is Empty

This field is not Empty

this is because i currently have only 2 recordsets in the DB and one contains data and the other does not. What i need from this is some sort of status indicator that will do the search as above but if it finds an empty field i need just one indicator and not like above where it is displaying text for all the recordsets.

Comment: I have just tested the following and it works perfectly except for the fact that it only checks the first recordset. I need it to check all recordsets within the table.

Comment: <%

If (Recordset1.Fields.Item("A").Value) = "" OR (Recordset1.Fields.Item("B").Value) = "" Then
Response.Write("This field is Empty")
Else
Response.Write("This field is not Empty")
End If

%>

Comment: Hi Lee. Welcome to StackOverflow. Firstly you should take the [tour] and acquaint yourself with the ethos of SO. Also, read this section on [*How to ask a question*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: That said, show us the code you have, and give us an estimate of where you think you're going wrong. As a tip, in you piece of code in the comment directly above, you'll need to ensure that there is data in the field, and, if so, what type of data it is. Whichever way you do this you'll need to enforce a conversion to that data type. One easy way is to cast to a string by appending an empty string to our field value using the concatenation operator `&` - i.e. `If Recordset1.Fields.Item("A").Value & "" = "" Then...`

Answer (score 0):

You can LOOP through your recordset to check all records not just the first one. Something like;

```
WHILE NOT Recordset1.EOF

IF Recordset1("A") = "" THEN
    Response.Write("This field is Empty")
ELSE
    Response.Write("This field is not Empty")
END IF

IF Recordset1("B") = "" THEN
    Response.Write("This field is Empty")
ELSE
    Response.Write("This field is not Empty")
END IF

Recordset1.MoveNext
WEND
```